# Live activity push notification using Amazon SNS

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sns

I am trying to send live activity push notification using Amazon ANS using the following code

```
 SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)))
            .build();
    MessageAttributeValue v1 = MessageAttributeValue.builder().dataType("String").stringValue("<bundle_ID>.push-type.liveactivity").build();
    MessageAttributeValue v2 = MessageAttributeValue.builder().dataType("String").stringValue("liveactivity").build();
    MessageAttributeValue v3 = MessageAttributeValue.builder().dataType("String").stringValue("10").build();
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attributeValueMap = Map.of(
            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TOPIC", v1,
            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE", v2,
            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY", v3);

    PlatformPayload platformPayload = PlatformPayload.builder().APNS(payload).build();
    String jsonPayload = new Gson().toJson(platformPayload);
    PublishRequest publishRequest = PublishRequest.builder().targetArn(endPointArn)
            .message(jsonPayload)
            .messageStructure("json")
            .messageAttributes(attributeValueMap)
            .build();
    PublishResponse publishResponse = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

Here I am getting success in sending the push notification, but the notification is not delivering to the device. I am using message attributes to pass additional information like push type in  **AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TOPIC** and **AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE** in message attributes. Also using p8 file instead of p12 file on SNS console.

If any one has sent live activity push using SNS please help.

Thanks